# Citing a group of functions in a centered block

Tags: formatting, citing

My professor told me that my citation is not placed rightly (see the "[8]" in the picture). I wonder what is the best way to cite a few functions? These functions are centered in my text as you can see. Should the citation go before or after the period?

[image]

Comment: I would place the citation in the text, not the equation: "… and it is defined inductively as follows \cite{Foo}."

Comment: This is off-topic, because it's a question on writing style. On the TeX side, your usage of `\bigcup` is wrong and `\cup` should be used in the middle equation. Also `\mathit{FV}` should be preferred instead of `FV` for a two letter name.